# How can I get my android app reviews and info Feed into my site from Google play

Tags: android, rss

How can i get my android app reviews and info.  Feed into my site from Google play... Same like the http://www.appbrain.com and other android play store doing... Getting all latest app info. directly from google play store

Answer (score 3):

Get all reviews from any Google App.

https://still-plateau-10039.herokuapp.com/reviews?id=mytown.preschool

id={google-app-id}

The service will return all the reviews on the app

Or simple host this locally
Source code of the service can be found at https://github.com/tohir87/googleplay-reviews